# getting junk value while display object

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

i am trying to implement a class with copy and swap idiom but while printing the object i am getting junk value. i am using copy-ctor to make use of copy before i make use of assignment. following is code snippet:

```
    class EmpTasks {
private: 
    size_t m_size; 
    char* name;
public:
    EmpTasks(char* name, int size = 0)
        : m_size(size),
        name(m_size ? new char[m_size] : nullptr){
    }


    EmpTasks(const EmpTasks& source)
        : m_size (source.m_size),
          name (source.name ? new char [m_size] : nullptr)
    {
        std::copy(source.name, source.name + m_size, name);
    }
    
    //copy assign operator
    EmpTasks& operator = (EmpTasks copy_form){
        swap(*this, copy_form);
        return *this;
    }


    friend void swap (EmpTasks& first, EmpTasks& second) {
        //ADL
        using std::swap;

        swap(first.m_size, second.m_size);
        swap(first.name, second.name);
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const EmpTasks& ep) {
        return os << "Employee name: " << ep.name << endl;
    }

    ~EmpTasks()
    {
        delete[] name; 
    }
};
```

here is main snippet. what is it that i am doing wrong.

```
const int size = 14;
char name[size] = "Some string";
EmpTasks ep (name, size);
cout << ep << endl;
```

Comment: You never use `name` argument passed to your constructor.

Comment: `const int size = 8; char name[size] = "Some string";` -- There's more than 8 characters in that string literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this has occurred because you haven't initialized your var `name`, hence you can use something like what follows in your ctor

```
EmpTasks(char* name, int size = 0)
        : m_size(size),
          name( m_size ? new char[m_size] : nullptr ){
    for(size_t i{}; i< m_size; ++i)
        this -> name[i] = name[i];
}
```

Another thing. `name[size] = "Some string";` here `"Some string"` must be < 8 chars

And I think you should consider the following version of copy assignment operator

```
//copy assign operator
EmpTasks& operator = (const EmpTasks& copy_form){
    if(this == & copy_form) return *this;//checks for self-assignment
    EmpTasks temp{copy_form};//uses cpy ctor
    std::swap(*this, temp);//remember to delete your `swap`
    return *this;
}
```

Because yours is not a copy assignment operator because its parameter is not constant and not taken by reference.

Note that `name` requires a null terminator `'\0'`when used with standard library functions like `std::operator<<`, so the size of it should be at least number of characters + 1.